# postMessage() in iframe fails, because `document.referrer` returns empty string in iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor

I’m having a problem where a vendor’s javascript is throwing an error because document.referrer returns an empty string as a parameter being sent to `postMessage()`.

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
> Ionic Framework               :
> @ionic/angular 6.0.14    @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.2.17
> @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.17    @angular/cli
> : 12.2.17    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI   : 3.4.3    @capacitor/core : 3.4.3
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res                          : 0.15.4    native-run (update
> available: 1.6.0) : 1.5.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v14.18.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)    npm    : 6.14.15    OS
> : macOS Monterey

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to that? We are having a very similar problem running react native web app wrapped in expo...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment above, we had a **very similar** issue, except we are are running react native web app wrapped in expo.

**The short answer is, make sure you set up the right "referrer policy" for your application.**

A bit longer answer:

Our third party widget worked everywhere except our dev environment. After days of debugging I realized that somehow our referrer policy is overwritten in our dev env (Azure setup).

Modern browsers set the referrer policy to `"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"`, which sets `document.referrer` to your origin url.

We had our set to `"same-origin"` in one of our environments and this header doesn't share its origin with the cross origin destination, therefore, when the third party widget tried to `postMessage` back to us, we would get nothing, because `document.referrer` was empty.

Here's more info on [Referrer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)